# Change text color and line gutter in Android Studio

Tags: android, colors, editor

I want to change the text color and line gutter to enhance the look of the editor window but i couldn't find anything about it.

[Screenshot of the current editor window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWdLr.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the android studio theme.

**To Change Font Color :**

```
File->Settings->Editor->Colors & Fonts->
```

**To Change Android Studio Theme :**

Follow the steps :

- Go to File -> Settings -> Appearance&Behaviour -> Appearance
- Change the theme to whatever you like.
- Then restart the android studio.

[image]

**For Custome Them for Android Studio :**

[Android Studio Custom Theme](http://www.androidstudiothemes.com/)

Comment: Thanks you !! I forgot to find in defaut color font

Comment: Happy to help :)